Как в скрипте указать логин и пароль от учетной записи git?
Пытался сделать через ssh, но репозитрий говорит, что не поддерживает данный вид ssh взаимодействия с сервером.
Решил написать скрипт, котоорый выполняет все при запуске:
#!/bin/bash

cd ~/my_dir/
sudo -S <<< "my_pass" git pull 
sudo -S <<< "my_pass" systemctl restart my_service

Но при запуске, все равно требуется чтобы я ввел логин и парль от учетной записи, т.к. проект склонирован по HTTPS
Есть ли возможность как-то указать логин и пароль от git тут в скрипте, чтобы я не вводил каждый раз пароль?

Тут какая-то каша. Какое отношение локальный пользователь имеет к авторизации

Через скрипт не получится. Для github или gitlab можно использовать аутентификацию по токену вместо логина/пароля. Другие варианты - git credentials. Там есть варианты настройки от простого временного хранения логина/пароля в памяти, или хранения в файле в открытом виде до безопасного хранения в git credential manager: https://github.blog/2022-04-07-git-credential-manager-authentication-for-everyone/

"Пытался сделать через ssh, но репозитрий говорит, что не поддерживает данный вид ssh взаимодействия с сервером." - вместо мутного словестного описания надо было привести выполненные команды и вывод git. По ходу проблемы только в том, что репозиторий был склонирован по https. Для переключения на ssh достаточно было поменять origin url.

Попробуйте сделать с GitHub Desktop. Вы там просто регистрируйтесь, и когда вы пытаетесь запускать git-команды, вас будут спрашивать, с каким именно аккаунтом вы будете делать этот запрос. И вам не требуется постоянно написать пароль и логин.

Во-общем, выкрутился через настройки .git/config:
[url "git@RepoDomain.ru:MyUser/MyProject.git"]
        insteadOf = https://RepoDomain.ru/project/MyUser/MyProject.git

Не знаю почему, но оно сработало и сразу же сервер по ssh смог обновление без пароля провести обновление (естественно ранее я настраивал доступ по ssh).

"Не знаю почему" - ответ стоит приводить, когда была выяснена причина роблемы.
